# "Could not find the required '{Assemly}.deps.json'. This file should be present at the root of the deployment package

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda

I have .Net Core2.1 code that I want to deploy to AWS Lambda. I don't want to use Visual studio to publish my code to Lambda I want to publish it using .net core cli. I ran command with

> dotnet publish /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true

I zipped up my deployment and load it into Lambda AWS console. 
But when I run the lambda I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "LambdaException",
  "errorMessage": "Could not find the required 'RSSFeedStartService.deps.json'.  This file should be present at the root of the deployment package."
}
```

I can see that `RSSFeedStartService.deps.json` is in the deployment package. it is part of my zipped deployment
Why does it keep complaining that it is not there?

Comment: "I zipped up my deploymen" .. what path did you zip up? At the end, `dotnet publish` prints out a directory that ends with `/publish/`. You should copy that directory, and not any other.

Comment: That's what I uploaded to the lambda the publish directory, but you have to compress it into a zip file in order to upload it to Lambda.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was zipping the package incorrectly. The actual publish directory was included in the zip, which explains the "This file should be present at the **root** of the deployment package" part of the error.

This is what ended up working (assuming you're on Linux/Mac):

```
dotnet publish -o publish
cd publish
zip -r ../publish.zip *
```

Then I uploaded `publish.zip` with the Lambda console.

(Tip: Run `unzip -l publish.zip` to see the contents of the zip. It should *not* include `publish/` before the files.)

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I renamed the lambda function. Fixed It by correcting function name in the `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json`

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by going to the AWS Lambda function itself to view the package.

If you go to AWS->Lambda->Functions->{Your Function} and then use Actions->Export function, you can look at the actual artifacts that the lambda is trying to use.

When I found that the .ZIP file was empty, I realized that our DevOps pipeline wasn't properly copying the files over.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to fix this.

1. Installed [AWS Lambda .NET CLI tool extension](https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli) with following command.

> dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools

2. Deployed the Lambda function by running the following command on a terminal (command prompt) in the Lambda function's project root directory.

> dotnet lambda deploy-function < LambdaFunctionProjectFile >

(As a prerequisite, you should have configured the AWS CLI in order complete this.)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and looks like this could happen for many reasons. Mine was that the root directory holding the solution had projectname(backup 1).csproj files. I have no idea how those came there, but .deps.json missing issue went away after removing those files and redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, redeploying the lambda helped

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to copy build files 1 level up.
The console was complaining that there is no deps.json file in \bin\Debug\net6.0, while visual studio was putting all the files to \bin\Debug\net6.0\win-x64. I just copied the files and everything is working fine now.